# Firestore whereField( ,ArrayContainsAny: ) Pops error that says it does not match available overloads

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I put the .whereField just as it shows on the documentation and it does not seem to work
 in the image I have my code.
And this is what I have on top of viewDidLoad

```
var listener : ListenerRegistration!
var db = Firestore.firestore()
var Tags = [String]()
```

This is the code inside mi func:

```
let docRef = db.collection("Clothes")

    docRef.whereField("tags", arrayContainsAny: Tags).order(by: "timeStamp", descending: true)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to type "arrayContainsAny" with a lowercase a, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) and [API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#wherefield_:arraycontainsany:)?

Comment: Yes thats how i had it at first but it did not work either

Comment: Can you show how `Tags` is initialized? It's most likely not an array, and the method expects `[Any]`.

Comment: I initialized it like this: `var Tags = [String]()` @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Please edit your question to include that. There should be no open ends in the code. For example, my next question would be what version of the SDK you're running as this was introduced in Version 6.12.0 on November 5, 2019 https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_6120_-_november_5_2019

Comment: I just took a look and I am on 6.1.0, should I update all my firebase pods to 6.21.0? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: 6.1.0 < 6.12.0, so that would explain the absence of the method you're calling. You'll need to upgrade to 6.12.0 or later to use the method.

Answer (score 0):

The `.whereField(..., arrayContainsAny:)` method was introduced in [version 6.12.0 of the Firestore SDK](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_6120_-_november_5_2019), and it seems like you're running a version older than that. You'll have to upgrade to version 6.12.0 to use the `.whereField(..., arrayContainsAny:)` method.

I'd recommend always checking for the latest version of the SDK on documentation page for [adding Firebase to an iOS app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).